# using internet service in Android App development

Tags: android

How should I request for web service of the device so that my app can use internet facility.
I have made an app using intent handling so that some web page could be opened via this app. But that made use of the device's web browser.
I just want my app to use the internet service(without needing for the web browser)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As above, use a webview which is as simple as:

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.example.com");
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
 startActivity(intent);
```

However, make sure you put this in your permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

source: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use [webview](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) to get the websites on your app.